# Does the language of the propositional calculus belong to some type of languages in Chomsky hierarchy (regular, CFL, CSL, recursive, r.e.)?

Tags: logic, computer-science, propositional-calculus, formal-languages

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Generic_description_of_a_propositional_calculus

> A propositional calculus is a formal system ${\mathcal {L}}={\mathcal {L}}\left(\mathrm {A} ,\ \Omega ,\ \mathrm {Z} ,\ \mathrm {I} \right)$. ...

> The language of $\mathcal {L}$, also known as its set of formulas, well-formed formulas, is inductively defined by the following rules:

> Base: Any element of the alpha set $\mathrm {A}$  is a formula of $\mathcal {L}$.

> If $p_{1},p_{2},\ldots ,p_{j}$ are formulas and $f$ is in $\Omega_{j}$, then $\left(f(p_{1},p_{2},\ldots ,p_{j})\right)$ is a formula.

> Closed: Nothing else is a formula of $\mathcal {L}$.

Does the language of the propositional calculus $\mathcal {L}$ belong to some type of languages in Chomsky hierarchy (regular, CFL, CSL, recursive, r.e.)?

If yes, why? (what is its grammar?)

Thanks.

Comment: I just realized that It is undecidable whether any given language is context-free. But can whether a specific language is context free  be decidable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When settling for $p, p', p'', \ldots$ as propositoinal variables, sticking to prefix notation and restricting oneself to a fixed set of operators, the language of propositional logic can be given as a **context-free grammar**:

$\langle \{F, P, U, B\}, \{\neg, \land, \lor, \to, p, ', "(", ")", ","\}, R, F \rangle$, where $R =\{$

$
F \longrightarrow P\\
F \longrightarrow U(F)\\
F \longrightarrow B(F,F)\\
U \longrightarrow \neg\\
B \longrightarrow \land\\
B \longrightarrow \lor\\
B \longrightarrow \to\\
P \longrightarrow p\\
P \longrightarrow P'\\
\}$.

Comments:

- selection of operators:
  Generalizing over arbitrary $n$-ary connectives is not possible, because the number of symbols on each side of the rule is arbitrary but fixed (so we can not write "$\ldots$"), and there is no such thing as meta-variables either (so we can not write "$f^n$" to indicate that the arity of the operator matches the number of arguments), and the number of terminal nodes and the set of production rules in a formal grammar is finite (so we can not have arbitrary, infinitely many operators).
  This is not so much of a problem because normally one does pick a fixed set of operators for one's dialect of propositional logic, and the "If $f$ is an $n$-ary operator ..." clause is only a useful abbreviation for summing up a bunch of cases when writing up the inductive definition, while the actual rule set for that variation the language is finite. It's just that formal grammars can't account for the generalization as the family of all such languages with arbitrary operators.
- propositional variables:
  This formulation assumes a simple recursive numbering scheme for propositional variables: $p, p', p'', \ldots$; a numbering scheme in the decimal format as suggested in your source is possible in an analogous manner. Already numbered variables can not be treated as terminal nodes because there are countable infinitely many of them, but as stated above, the definition of a formal grammar requires the set of terminal nodes and the set of production rules to be finite; so one has to settle for some kind of recursive numbering scheme. Again, not much of a problem because there is no reason why you'd want some wild non-recursively enumerable naming scheme for propositoinal variables.
- auxiliary symbols:
  Note that in this formulation, the parentheses and the comma are part of the alphabet of the formal language of PL, not of the grammar formalism.
- writing conventions:
  Conventions such as infix notation ("$A \land B$" instead of "$\land(A, B)$") and omission of parentheses ("$A \land B \land C$" instead of "$((A \land B) \land C)$", "$A \to B \land C$" instead of "$(A \to (B \land C))$") would have to be appropriately translated into respective production rules as well.
- infix notation:
  The rules in infix notation would then be $\{, \ldots, F \longrightarrow UF, F \longrightarrow FBF, \ldots\}$.
- omission of parentheses:
  A perhaps interesting point is that operator associativity and precedence would make the language context-sensitive, because the presence or absence of parentheses depends on which context of other operators the subformula occurs in. However, omission of parentheses is usually treated as syntactic sugar on the surface representation while in the underlying formal languages has all parentheses present, so one wouldn't typically explicitly encode these omission rules in the grammar.

Comment: The definition quoted in the question allows a more general set $\Omega$ of connectives, which should also be finite for a traditional (finite) CFG to work. Also, the definition in the question uses prefix notation with parentheses and commas, so technically your CFG should have, for example, $\land(F,F)$ rather than $F\land F$. But +1 for showing that the definition in the question essentially **is** a CFG.

Comment: @andreas the quoted definition has a finite number of connectives, so it is CF. Since each connective has a valence and the valence of the call must match, it wouldn't be context-free if there weren't a finite number of possible valences.

Comment: Fair points; I extended my answer.

Comment: @rici I've re-read the question, and I still see nothing there saying that $\Omega$ is finite.

Comment: @andreas: "The omega set Ω is a finite set of elements called operator symbols or logical connectives." Is the second para in the wikipedia article. I guess it would have been better to have said "the *cited* definition" rather than "the quoted definition". Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @lemontree: if the proposition s in the set $A$ are written using some simple coding scheme with a finite alphabet (such as binary numbers), then the problem vanishes. I think that's just a technical fix.

Comment: @rici Of course, thanks for the hint.

Comment: I just realized that It is undecidable whether any given language is context-free. But can whether a specific language is context free  be decidable?

Comment: There may be no algorithm that will do this for you for any given language (I'd have to look this up again), but if you somehow managed to find a context-free grammar that generates the language, this is proof enough that the language is context-free.

Comment: " It's just that formal grammars can't account for the generalization as the family of all such languages with arbitrary operators." Do you mean your CFG generate only a proper subset of the language of the propositional calculus, without  $f$'s?

Comment: There is not really "the" language of PL; which symbols you define to be part of the language depends on taste. And it not really matter, because you don't need a dedicated symbol for each of the infinitely many conceivable truth-functional operators to express all of PL, as long as you choose a functionally complete set of operators (one of which the above is). You might want to look into functional completeness.